# jQuery :selected always returns the first option

Tags: jquery, selected, selectedvalue

I'm trying to build a control function to check that at least an expected option from a select list is selected by the user.

I've built this function that works, except that it always returns me the first option value for the first element from the loop.

Example : for a select list with 1 : 'foo' and 2 : 'bar', the alert returns me 'foo' even if I chose 'bar' in the first select list, but it's right for the next select values.

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#submit", function() {
        var n = 0;
        for (var p = 0; p < index; p++) {
            var selectValue = $('#multiple_answer_'+p+'_option :selected').val();
            n++;
            alert('option '+n+' : '+selectValue)
        } 
});
```

Comment: Could you create a fiddle for this? I'm not sure I understand the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your'e using `.val()` to retrieve the value of a select there is no need for `:selected`

```
var selectValue = $('#multiple_answer_'+p+'_option').val();
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aAURL/1/

**Also note**, the array is zero indexed so the id elements must start with `multiple_answer_0_option`.

Comment: Indeed, works without :selected but I still get the first option for my first select list.

Comment: @SirBeute Do your id's start at 0 meaning `multiple_answer_0_option`?

Comment: That is the fix? Or they are named appropriately?

Comment: This number is generated by Symfony's embed forms. I think I can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are selecting $('#multiple_answer_'+p+'_option' ... which is only one on your page. '#' is added before id value of the item, and this value should be unique.

You should rather use 'class' or other attribute, which does not have to be unique, to make selections.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#submit').change(function(){ 
    var text = $(this).val();
    alert(text);
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZCJt/)

Comment: The problem is that I have a random number of select items to check, whence the for loop.